# Execute class in submodule during maven build

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have a multimodule maven project and I like to execute a java class during the build of the multimodule.

The Java class is part of a submodule, so I tried to add the `exec-maven-plugin`, but it always fail with a `ClassNotFoundException`

The part looks like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-dump</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
        <mainClass>org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.Coffeelint2Java</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>${rules.path}</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This results in

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/check/Priority
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.CheckTemplateWriter.getPriority(CheckTemplateWriter.java:126)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.CheckTemplateWriter.checkLevelLine(CheckTemplateWriter.java:107)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.CheckTemplateWriter.lambda$generateReplacementMapping$3(CheckTemplateWriter.java:86)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.CheckTemplateWriter$$Lambda$5/161691919.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.CheckTemplateWriter.generateReplacementMapping(CheckTemplateWriter.java:84)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.CheckTemplateWriter.generate(CheckTemplateWriter.java:52)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.Coffeelint2Java.doGenerateChecks(Coffeelint2Java.java:72)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.Coffeelint2Java.generateChecks(Coffeelint2Java.java:59)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.Coffeelint2Java.lambda$generateChecks$1(Coffeelint2Java.java:51)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.Coffeelint2Java$$Lambda$4/1333998550.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.Coffeelint2Java.generateChecks(Coffeelint2Java.java:51)
at org.sonar.plugins.coffeelint2java.Coffeelint2Java.main(Coffeelint2Java.java:41)
... 6 more
```

The sonar dependency is defined in the parent pom, but also when I add it to the `<dependency>` section in the submodule pom, it returns the same result.

How do I need to define the pom correctly, to include the dependencies when executing the main class ?

=== UPDATE ===
The dependency in the parent pom is

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.sslr-squid-bridge</groupId>
        <artifactId>sslr-squid-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The submodule itself also adds other dependencies

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
        <version>1.48</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And right after updating my question and adding the dependency information to it, I saw it myself.

the provided attribute was the problem. argh

removing it solved the problem

Comment: Indeed, I was going to answer the same. Well seen. Think about accepting your own answer so that this question will not appear as unanswered any longer.